# how to make show and hide paragraph using checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

what i try to achieve  in my below code by default home heading and  paragraph is not show when i click on home checkbox then its show

and also when i unclick then its hide

my functionality is working fine in below code but i am not able to achieve this

when i click on home checkbox then paragraph its show and when unclick then its hide

check on my below code i post in my code when i run the file by default home paragraph is show.

but i want to achieve after click checkbox then show all the things. And i want to try when i run the page only checkbox is show after click checkbox then show and hide the things.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction1() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck1");
  var text1 = document.getElementById("text1");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text1.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text1.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
  var text2 = document.getElementById("text2");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text2.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="myFunction2()">home
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">menu 1
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction1()">menu 2

 
</div>


<div class="container">
  <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" id="text2" style="display:none">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="text" style="display:none">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
  <li class="nav-item" id="text1" style="display:none">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#abc">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active" ><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
    
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
     
    </div>
     <div id="abc" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

is there any help on this its very thankful.

Comment: You dont need to use js functions when you are using bootstrap 4

Comment: so how can we do that without js function how can we do show and hide??

Comment: Please check this for nav and pills https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navs/

Comment: Bootstrap is already equiped with some pre-made elements and components with basic css and js with them you just need to use them. You have already imported the bootstrap min css and js in your webpage so use what's already available rather than making your own.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan same thing i used u check my code but want to try in here when click on check box then its show and unclick then its hide

Comment: Yeah but you are trying to do it manually by inline styles but you see using nav and pills gives your elements those bootstrap classes that show/hide them. So if you are trying to do it by checkboxes, you first need to understand which classes are being changed at bootstrap level for you `tab-pane`

Comment: Well anyways I would say that you need to add remove `active` and `fade` classes from those paragraph divs for them to show hide. They already have `tab-pane active` for show and `tab-pane fade` for hide so if you want to toggle it by your own js, you should toggle the active/fade classes in them

Comment: Or you can go more into nav and pills and see if you can play with it by giving your checkboxes these data `data-toggle="pill" href="#home"` and playing with it

Comment: thanks for this but i want to try when i click on checkbox then its show tab-pane  and when i click on uncheck then its hide the tab pane how can we do  that is there some any method or suggestion

Comment: i m unable to do that can u show me something like that what i try to achieve its very thankful

Comment: For that you need to remove this `text.style.display = "block";` and add class to it by `text.classList.add("active"); text.classList.remove("fade");` and vice-versa

Comment: data-toggle="pill" href="#home" this one is not work

Comment: can you help me with remotely ???.its very thankful and much appreciation

Comment: Fine... Try my answer

Comment: text.classList.add("active"); text.classList.remove("fade"); no this is not work

Comment: can we connect remotely ??

Comment: Give me a moment I'll check

Comment: text.classList.add("active"); text.classList.remove("fade"); what is that vice versa ???

Comment: ok suree thanks for ur tym

Comment: vice versa means *jese ko tesa* means opposite of something in reverse order

Comment: yes i am doing that but its not work

Comment: Chek now it will work 

Answer (score 0):

I used two functions here for simplicity. First is your original `myFunction()` which picks the individual elements by ids and show hide them. I used `active` and `fade` classes to show hide bootstrap nav pills respectively. To show a `tab-pane` you need to append `active` class and remove `fade` class and to hide it you need to remove `active` class and add `fade` class.

Now for the second dynamic method `hideShowById(event)` I used the target element information which I took by event and did the same show hide procedure except the fact that the data has been picked out from source element just like bootstrap does.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("menu1");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.classList.add("active");
    text.classList.remove("fade");
  } else {
    text.classList.remove("active");
    text.classList.add("fade");
  }
}

function hideShowById(event) {
  var checkBoxChecked = event.checked;
  var text = document.getElementById(event.getAttribute('data-toggle'));
  if (checkBoxChecked == true){
    text.classList.add("active");
    text.classList.remove("fade");
  } else {
    text.classList.remove("active");
    text.classList.add("fade");
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="container">
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="hideShowById(this)" data-toggle="home" checked>
  <label for="myCheck2">home</label>
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
  <label for="myCheck">menu 1</label>
  <input class="mr-1" type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="hideShowById(this)" data-toggle="abc">
  <label for="myCheck1">menu 2</label>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" id="text2" style="display:none">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="text" style="display:none">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
  <li class="nav-item" id="text1" style="display:none">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#abc">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>      
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    </div>
     <div id="abc" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: can we discuss over meet link is it possible

Comment: when i use this code then show and hide not work

Comment: @soumyasingh check if this is what you are looking for then I'll explain the logic