# Laravel checkbox on checked set div to be active

Tags: javascript, laravel-8

I have a foreach loop where I will populate timeslot ID, dates, and time on a div. What I want to achieve is upon checking the checkbox in the div, the selected div will be highlighted. And if I try to checked the other checkbox, it will unchecked the previous one that I have checked. I am using native javascript for my javascript codes.

[This is how the checkbox looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35oQ0.png)

Below are my html codes:

```
    <div class="timeslots-section">
       <div>
           <div class="timeslots text-center">
              @foreach ($timeslots as $timeslot)
              <div class="timeslot" id="timeslot">
              <input type="checkbox" id="timeslotchk" name="timeslot" value="{{$timeslot->timeslotID}}"> 
              <label>{!! presentTableDate($timeslot->deliveryDate) !!}</label>
              <label>{!! displayTime($timeslot->deliveryStartTime) !!} - 
              {!! displayTime($timeslot->deliveryEndTime) !!}</label>
             </div>
             @endforeach
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Below are my current javascript:

```
var selectall = document.getElementsById('timeslotchk');
            var timeslotdiv = document.getElementById('timeslot');
            selectall.onclick = function() {
                if(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked = true){
               timeslotdiv.classList.add('active');
                }
                else{
               timeslotdiv.classList.remove('active');

                }
            }
```

Comment: First I would say do not use same `id` in those checkboxes when its in foreach loop. Second, use class in your JavaScript code not id

Comment: Im using foreach loop to populate the datas from my database, so is it ok if they have the same class?

Comment: Yes classes can be same but ids cannot be same

Comment: I have changed the javascript as you have suggested, however the div is still nt highlighted even tho the checkbox has been checked. Where seems to be the issue?

Comment: Console the items after you change them to see if they are getting the `active` class properly or not. Make sure the events are being triggered properly. If not then add onchange event in checkbox directly instead of addEventListener

Comment: Same like I did in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66565305/how-to-make-show-and-hide-paragraph-using-checkbox/66565664?noredirect=1#comment117673140_66565664

Comment: I tried your solution and it still doesn't work, I edited my codes and currently, only the div of the first checkbox is `active`.

Comment: Below is the code I have. `const timeslotDiv = document.querySelector('.timeslot');
            const selectElement = document.querySelectorAll('.timeslotchk');
            
            selectElement.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('change', checkboxChecked));

            function checkboxChecked(e){
                if(this.checked){
                    timeslotDiv.classList.add('active');
                }
                else{
                    timeslotDiv.classList.remove('active');

                }
            }`

Comment: You were half way there. Check my answer I tried it with plain html since I can't run the blade foreach here. The idea is simple, we first reset all the divs and then set the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here check this I fixed the function you were trying. Your code was not resetting all the other `timeslot` divs when the current one is checked. In the below code the change event function `checkboxChecked()` first reset all the divs including the current one and then checks for the changed value. If the current checkbox was checked `true` then set it else keep it reset.

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelectorAll('.timeslotchk');     
selectElement.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('change', checkboxChecked));

function checkboxChecked() {
  const checked = this.checked; //save current value
  //reset all time slot divs
  const timeslotDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('timeslot');
  Array.from(timeslotDivs).forEach(function(t) {
    t.classList.remove('active');
    t.querySelector('.timeslotchk').checked = false;
  });
  //set current div based on current value
  if(checked) {
    this.checked=true;
    this.parentNode.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.timeslot {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeslots-section">
  <div>
     <div class="timeslots text-center">
       <!-- @foreach ($timeslots as $timeslot) -->
        <div class="timeslot active">
          <input class="timeslotchk" type="checkbox" name="timeslot" value="timeslotID"  checked>
          <label>(deliveryDate)</label>
          <label>
           (deliveryStartTime) - (deliveryEndTime)
          </label>
        </div>
         <div class="timeslot">
          <input class="timeslotchk" type="checkbox" name="timeslot" value="timeslotID"> 
          <label>(deliveryDate)</label>
          <label>
           (deliveryStartTime) - (deliveryEndTime)
          </label>
        </div>
         <div class="timeslot">
          <input class="timeslotchk" type="checkbox" name="timeslot" value="timeslotID"> 
          <label>(deliveryDate)</label>
          <label>
           (deliveryStartTime) - (deliveryEndTime)
          </label>
        </div>
         <div class="timeslot">
          <input class="timeslotchk" type="checkbox" name="timeslot" value="timeslotID"> 
          <label>(deliveryDate)</label>
          <label>
           (deliveryStartTime) - (deliveryEndTime)
          </label>
        </div>
       <!-- @endforeach -->
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tested your codes out and it works well with the foreach loop! Thanks so much for the explanation!

Comment: @junmingyeo98 I told you it will work. Anyways accept it 

Comment: Accept the answer